# What are the ukulele chord names he played in this tutorial?

Tags: chords, ukulele

So I know he isn’t saying all the chord names correctly since they’re being altered and I was curious of the technical chord names in this tutorial.

Comment: Try out a chord finder such as [this one](https://ukebuddy.com/chord-namer) to identify the names of ukulele chords.